# regex match word and characters before and after in the same word

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I want to get a match on a specific word even though the word is surrounded by other characters. For instance:

```
Regex: ($|\W)(.*?vård.*?)($|\W)

Sentence: bedriva serviceverksamhet och en som ska bedriva asdasdvårdssss jheksamas asd asd asd

Match right now:  serviceverksamhet och en som ska bedriva asdasdvårdvå

Wanted Match: asdasdvårdssss
```

So how do I get it to stop the match at space before the word just as it does after the word?

It is also important to that the match stops if there is a word break like "." or "," etc.

I have the same problem in both C# and JS so if there is any differences it would be nice to consider.

Comment: Maybe `\S*vård\S*` will be enough (`\S` matches any non-whitespace). Note that in C#, `\w*vård\w*` will work since `\w` is Unicode aware in .NET regex.

Comment: Both C# and JS since i have this problem on two different places.

Comment: Also i think that your solution will only stop the match on space. I still want it to stop if there is a word delimiter like "," or "." or so on. Thats why i used the .*? i think

Comment: The problem is that JS and .NET regex engines differ greatly. As I mentioned, you may use `\w*vård\w*` in .NET, but in JS, you'd need to use XRegExp library to match all Unicode letters.

Comment: Your first non-character match should have `^`, not `$` - `(^|\W)` which makes your issue clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to include non-word characters, don't include them:

```
var pattern = @"(^|\W)(\w*vård\w*)($|\W)";
```